# Confusion about assumptions in classification problems

Tags: regression, probability, bayesian, classification, independence

I was studying Linear Discriminant Analysis, and this general case came up which used Bayes theorem.

Suppose we observed response values of $Y \in \{0,1\}$ and predictors $X \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose we didn't know their underlying distributions, but we generated them as $X|Y=0 \sim Unif(0,0.5)$ and $X|Y=1 \sim Unif(1,1.5)$ where $Y \sim Bern(p), p \in (0,1)$.

By Bayes theorem, for $k \in \{0,1\}$ we obtain the distribution $$\mathbb{P}[Y=k|X=x]=\frac{f_{X}(x|Y=k)\mathbb{P}[Y=k]}{f_{X}(x)}=\frac{f_{X}(x|Y=k)\mathbb{P}[Y=k]}{f_{X}(x|Y=0)\mathbb{P}[Y=0]+f_{X}(x|Y=1)\mathbb{P}[Y=1]}.$$

My friend and I had a discussion about just modelling $f_{X}(x)$, and introducing assumptions gradually.

**My question is**, **what can we assume about an observed sample $X_1,...,X_n$ (i.e. whether they are independent and/or identically distributed) given**

1. we had just observed values of $X$ and didn't assume any classes existed
2. we observed classes (i.e. a sample $Y_1,...,Y_n$), but didn't know the form of the conditional distributions
3. we knew that the conditional distribution of $X$ was uniform
4. we knew the parameters of the uniforms and $p$